# Incorrect month is updated automatically on WordPress published post

Tags: wordpress

When i set write a post, it is by default set to publish Immediately. When i publish it, published month is changed itself. Like if i'm publishing it today on 19-Oct-2018, after publishing the post, published date is set 19-Sept-2018.

I have deleted all the plugins to see if something has any impact but no vain.

Please see the image to understand the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUrZJ.png)

Comment: can you show us the code inside the file, where this date is returned ?

Comment: I'm afraid, I can't find that where there is the code which is pressed when publish button is pressed.

Comment: when i open the settings and General settings, there in date format, it is also showing the previous month. This behaviour shows that there's some system level problem. I checked the date time of server and that is fine.

Comment: Sounds like the theme (or server) you are using has the timezone set incorrectly. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308104/wordpress-returns-a-wrong-date will help you sort it out.

Comment: incorrect time zone can effect the date or time only, not the month. It's the month which is showing wrong. Now it's Oct but it is showing Sept.

Comment: Did you read https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308104/wordpress-returns-a-wrong-date ?